# Inferring relative frequencies in partially observed Dirichlet-Multinomial

Tags: bayesian, mathematical-statistics, inference, dirichlet-distribution, multinomial-dirichlet-distribution

I am working with this example. I have a set of multinomial data with $N$ rows and $D+1$ categories drawn from buckets of different size, $M_n$: $$ \mathbf{p}_{D+1}~\sim~\text{Dirichlet}(\mathbf{a}_{D+1})\\ \mathbf{y}_{n}~\sim~\text{Multinomial}(M_n,~\mathbf{p}_{D+1})$$

I wish to learn the relative frequencies of the first $D$ components of the posterior for $\mathbf{p}$, i.e. $$q_{d} = \frac{p_{d}}{\sum_{j=1}^{D}p_{d}}.$$

Alternatively I could learn the equivalent model with just those first $D$ parameters, i.e. I drop the last column of my data and instead calculate $$\mathbf{p}_{D+1}~\sim~\text{Dirichlet}(\mathbf{a}_{D})\\ \mathbf{y}_{n, D}~\sim~\text{Multinomial}(M_n - y_{n, D+1},~\mathbf{p}_{D}^{*})$$ (where $\mathbf{a}_{D}$ are simply the first $D$ components of the vector $\mathbf{a}_{D+1}$) and learn the posterior for $\mathbf{p}_{D}^{*}$.

My question is whether the relative frequencies estimated for the first case are equal to those for the second, i.e. $\mathbf{q} = \mathbf{p}_{D}^{*}$. The reason I am interested in this setup is that $y_{n, D+1}$ is unobservable in my dataset. My instinct is that the answer is obviously yes, since due to the simplex sampling space of $\mathbf{p}$ the rescaling I perform for $q_d$ is implicit. The following code snippet suggests that this is the case:

```
library(MCMCprecision)
alpha <- c(20, 10, 5, 6, 8, 2)
N <- 10000
xfull <- rdirichlet(N, alpha)
xsub <- rdirichlet(N, alpha[2:length(alpha)])

xfullsub <- xfull[, 2:length(alpha)]
xfullsub <- xfullsub/rowSums(xfullsub)

print(colMeans(xfullsub))
print(colMeans(xsub))

print(cov(xfullsub))
print(cov(xsub))

...
> colMeans(xfullsub)
[1] 0.32205272 0.16228071 0.19275559 0.25859167 0.06431931
> colMeans(xsub)
[1] 0.32445834 0.15957880 0.19409470 0.25805411 0.06381406
> cov(xsub)
              [,1]          [,2]          [,3]          [,4]          [,5]
[1,]  0.0069050033 -0.0015408784 -0.0019659580 -0.0027251813 -0.0006729856
[2,] -0.0015408784  0.0042378620 -0.0010678030 -0.0013334961 -0.0002956845
[3,] -0.0019659580 -0.0010678030  0.0049890927 -0.0015923774 -0.0003629543
[4,] -0.0027251813 -0.0013334961 -0.0015923774  0.0061829670 -0.0005319123
[5,] -0.0006729856 -0.0002956845 -0.0003629543 -0.0005319123  0.0018635366
> cov(xfullsub)
              [,1]          [,2]          [,3]          [,4]          [,5]
[1,]  0.0068080012 -0.0015223084 -0.0019965425 -0.0026467176 -0.0006424327
[2,] -0.0015223084  0.0042819071 -0.0010962578 -0.0013639325 -0.0002994084
[3,] -0.0019965425 -0.0010962578  0.0049992621 -0.0015319462 -0.0003745155
[4,] -0.0026467176 -0.0013639325 -0.0015319462  0.0060368491 -0.0004942528
[5,] -0.0006424327 -0.0002994084 -0.0003745155 -0.0004942528  0.0018106093
```

but I am interested to know if there is a proof or manipulation of the Dirichlet-Multinomial distribution I am missing here. Alternatively this may be so obvious such a proof is unnecessary...

Any references or pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!